# How do I create the view for the has_one association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

So, imagine I have this model:

```
class Car
  has_one :engine
end
```

and the engine model:

```
class Engine
  belongs_to :car
end
```

When I present the form for the user, so that he can create a new car, I only want to allow him to select from one of the available engines ( the available engines will be in a `select`, populated by the `collection_select` ). The thing is, if I build the field like this:

```
<%= f.collection_select :engine,Engine.all,:id,:name %>
```

When I will try to save it, I will get an AssociationTypeMismatch saying that it expected an Engine, but it received a string.

Is this the way to do it?

```
def create
  car = Car.new(params[:car])
  engine = Engine.find(params[:engine])
  car.engine = engine
  if car.save
     # redirect somewhere
  else
     # do something with the errors
  end
end
```

I always felt that stuff, like associating an engine to a car, are done automatically by Rails, but I don't know how to make him do it.

Is switching the `has_one` and `belongs_to` associations the only way to achieve this?

I am lost and I feel like I'm missing something very basic here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should use `engine_id`

```
<%= f.collection_select :engine_id, Engine.all, :id, :name %>
```

**UPD**

as far as `Engine` is not belongs_to `Car` so you shoulduse Nested Attributes here. This screencast will be very useful for you:

- http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1
- http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2

Checkout api: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods/accepts_nested_attributes_for

Short intro:

```
class Car
  has_one :engine
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :engine
end
```

and in your form:

```
<%= form_for @car ... do |f| %>
  ...
  <%= f.fields_for :engine do |b| %>
    <%= b.collection_select :id, Engine.all, :id, :name %>
    ...
  <% end %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

Comment: So, even though the Engine is the one holding the association, I need to have an `engine_id` field in the Car model?

Comment: No! :) You should use `accepts_nested_attributes_for` here. I'll update my answer

Comment: And when I save the Car, I will also have access to the associated engine, using the `.engine` method,right?

Comment: But how do I populate the engines from a `collection_select`? Do I have to write `:engine_id` in the `fields_for`? Or just `id`?

Comment: I still have one small question. If I leave the view to be like `form_for @car`, then none of the fields in the `fields_for` are displaying. If I change the top-level form to `form_for :car`, they are displayed. Why is that?

Comment: fields for is looking for exist engines, so if you haven't got any for @car - nothing will appear, you should initialize it. Like `f.fields_for :engine, @car.build_ingine do |f| ...`

Comment: Thank you very much for all the patience and responses!

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem and here is my solution (improvements based on the **fl00r** answer):

1. Do everything as **fl00r** have said.
2. Add `optional: true` to the class description

> class Engine    belongs_to :car, optional: true  end

More info at: http://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/02/15/rails-5-makes-belong-to-association-required-by-default.html

2. Modify

> ```
> <%= f.fields_for :engine do |b| %>
>   <%= b.collection_select :id, Engine.all, :id, :name %>
>   ... 
> <% end %>
> ```

to

```
<%= f.fields_for :engine, :include_id => false do |b| %>
  <%= b.collection_select :id, Engine.all, :id, :name %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

More info at: [Stop rails from generating hidden field for fields_for method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10808731/stop-rails-from-generating-hidden-field-for-fields-for-method)

3. Modify your EngineController

3.1. Modify

```
def car_params
  params.require(:car).permit(:name)
end
```

to

```
def car_params
  params.require(:car).permit(:name, engine_attributes: [:id, :name])
end
```

More info at: [Rails 4 Nested Attributes Unpermitted Parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15919761/rails-4-nested-attributes-unpermitted-parameters)

3.1. Add a function (private)

```
def set_engine

  engine_id = car_params[:engine_attributes][:id]

  @engine = Engine.find(engine_id)

  @car.engine = @engine

  @car.save
end
```

3.2. Modify EngineController#update

```
  def update
    respond_to do |format|

      if @car.update(car_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @car, notice: 'Car was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @car }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @car.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

to

```
  def update
    respond_to do |format|

      if set_engine && @car.update(car_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @car, notice: 'Car was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @car }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @car.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

Response to previous answer from Kyle--I like this simple approach however I had to change it as follows to work for my app (I'm in Rails 3.2.13).  The main point was that the map needs to return an Array--so I think it was perhaps a typo putting two arrays separated by a comma. I also changed the string reference to the id attribute to a symbol but I'm not sure if this is essential or just another option.  At an rate, here is what worked for me.

```
<%= f.select :class_location_id, ClassLocation.all.map {|e| [e.place, e.id]} %>
```