# Stop rails from generating hidden field for fields_for method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I need to remove hidden id field that is being generated for existing records by `fields_for` method. Any idea how do do that?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

From [the docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html):

```
f.fields_for(:comments, :include_id => false)
```