# Rails nested attributes and changing associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes, accepts-nested-attributes

This one has had me stumped all day!

I have the following models:

**Pump class**

```
class Pump < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :control, as: :equipment
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :control
```

**Pump Schema**

```
class CreatePumps < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :pumps do |t|
      t.references :property, foreign_key: true, null: false
      t.string :name, default: 'Pump', null: false

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

**Control class**

```
class Control < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :equipment, polymorphic: true
```

**Control Schema**

```
class CreateControls < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :controls do |t|
      t.belongs_to :device, foreign_key: true, index: true
      t.integer :position, index: true
      t.references :equipment, polymorphic: true, index: true
      t.belongs_to :control_type, foreign_key: true, index: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

I'm trying to update the association between a **Control** and a **Pump**. The following works:

```
[439] pry(main)> Pump.first.update!(control: Control.find(62))
.
.
.
=> true
```

But the following doesn't and I can't figure out why.

```
[438] pry(main)> Pump.first.update(control_attributes: {id: 62}) 
   (0.4ms)  BEGIN
   (0.4ms)  ROLLBACK
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find Control with ID=62 for Pump 
with ID=1
from /usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-
5.1.5/lib/active_record/nested_attributes.rb:584:in 
`raise_nested_attributes_record_not_found!'
```

The context is that I have a form for a Pump and when editing my Pump, there's a list of Controls in a select drop-down. I would just like to choose which Control is associated with the pump.

**Update1:** Answering a question from below

```
 [468] pry(main)> Pump.first.update(control_attributes: {id: 62})
  Pump Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "pumps".* FROM "pumps" ORDER BY "pumps"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
  Control Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "controls".* FROM "controls" WHERE "controls"."equipment_id" = $1 AND "controls"."equipment_type" = $2 LIMIT $3  [["equipment_id", 1], ["equipment_type", "Pump"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.3ms)  ROLLBACK
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find Control with ID=62 for Pump with ID=1
from /usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-5.1.5/lib/active_record/nested_attributes.rb:584:in `raise_nested_attributes_record_not_found!'
```

Comment: Could you try with `Pump.first.update(control_attributes: [{id: 62}]) `

Comment: @GorillaApe output added to description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Pump.first.update(control_attributes: {id: 62})
```

Rails's nested attributes does't work this way! The code above means:

Find a control which's id is 62, and it's equipment_type should be "Pump", and it's equipment_id should be Pump.first.id, then update with **extra** params, which you did not provided.

You got this error because in the first step, the control with id 62, it's equipment_id isn't Pump.first.id

Like, to update name of the control which's id is 60, belongs to Pump.first, in correct association:

```
Pump.first.update(control_attributes: {id: 60, name: "xxxx"})
```

Comment: Thanks @lei-liu. I came to the same conclusion that 'accepts_nested_attributes_for' only allows you to update the attributes of a model with an existing relationship (or create a new one) and **not** establishing a new relationship.

I found the following reply to another question useful in what I'm trying to do - https://stackoverflow.com/a/38439414/9520908

Answer (score 1):

When you use `accepts_nested_attributes_for` for linked model, it will create new records when attributes are provided without `id` parameter. And it will update existing record linked with the parent record, when attributes are provided with `id` parameter.

`ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find Control with ID=62 for Pump 
with ID=1` : This error states that there is no `Control` record found for `Pump` object with the mentioned Ids.

You can add new control record for pump as:

```
Pump.first.update(control_attributes: { attribute1: 'attribute1_value' } )
```

This will create a new `Control` record associated with the `Pump` object having Id `1`. And now you can update this again as follows:

```
Pump.first.update(control_attributes: { id: 1, attribute1: 'updated_attribute1_value' } )
```

Note that `id` of the newly created Control record is taken as `1`.

Please read [through the documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) to get more details.

Hope this helps !

Comment: I think he wants to assign an existing control to pump

Comment: As @GorillaApe has correctly pointed out, I'm looking to connect an existing Control to a Pump. All of the Control objects are already created in the database.

Comment: Normally it should work. Could you update your question with your schema for the classes ?

Answer (score 0):

You could override the nested attributes setter method in the model so that it also updates the foreign key column directly.

```
# pump.rb
def control_attributes=(attributes)
  if (new_control = Control.find_by(id: attributes[:id]))
    self.control_id = new_control.id
  end

  super
end
```

Note: be careful about assigning the relation directly (i.e `self.control = new_control`) because that could result in some unexpected side effects if it is a has_one association defined with a `:dependent` option that results in deleting the record.